# Sql foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have a table with two FK from same table. I have following query:

I am attaching an Image: please let me know the error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put `,` char after 8th line as below

```
REFERENCES Teams(TeamID),
```

Comment: I forgot to add the comma. Thanks for noticing it.

Answer (score 2):

if you have created table Teams and Fixtures in the same session, Intellisense must be refreshed. If you have SQL error tell me and post your error.

P.S. use comma between two constraint rows

Comment: I forgot to add the comma. Thanks for noticing it.

Comment: Ok, have a nice day ;)